# ActivityManager.AppTasks issue

Tags: android

I want to know when emergency dialer is on the screen. So, I use this code but it doesn't even detect emergency dialer( Android api 21 and above ). Can anyone tell me what do I do wrong?

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.AppTask> tasks = am.getAppTasks();
            for(ActivityManager.AppTask task : tasks){
                Log.i("Point",task.getTaskInfo().baseIntent.getComponent().getPackageName()+" api 21");
            }
```

This code detects only my app.

```
06-12 17:23:02.172  29795-29795/? I/Point﹕ com.prjct3.amadey.myapplication3 api 21
```

Thanks.

Comment: That is because `getAppTasks()` is only supposed to return your own app's tasks. Quoting [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getAppTasks()): "Get the list of tasks associated with the calling application".

Comment: @commonsware So how can I do this?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't on Android 5.0+. Apps should not know what other apps are in the foreground, for privacy and security reasons.

Comment: @commonsware Can you please tell me  how can I obtain Class name from ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo ?

Comment: @commonsware Also Android Studio just show that getRunningTask() is deprecated but we can still use it, can't we?